# If ${f : X\to Y}$ is a continuous function with dense image, is the preimage of any non-empty open set non-empty?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

On page 25 of Hartshorne's book of Algebraic Geometry, he essentially says that a dominant morphism of varieties contravariantly induces a map on their function fields. For concluding this, he needs to use the fact that the preimage of a non-empty open subset under a dominant rational map is non-empty. Is it a general topological fact that if ${f : X\to Y}$ is a continuous map with dense image then the preimage of any non-empty open subset is non-empty? Or is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. Following your notation, the argument would go like this:
Let $U\subseteq Y$ be a non-empty open set. If $U\cap f(X)=\emptyset$, then $\overline{f(X)}\subseteq U^c$, which is a proper closed subset of $Y$. In particular, $f(X)$ is not dense.

By the way, this is equivalence (6) in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set.

Comment: Of course! I don't know why I didn't see this. This is perfect. Thank you!